# How to block some php variable from being used

Tags: php, security, disabled-input

Team i work with keep using `$_REQUEST` variable when i told them many times to not use it and instead use `$_POST` and `$_GET`. i wonder if there is way to block this variable so if they use it again code gives fatal error. Or perhaps deprecate it somehow.

e.g. i can put `unset($_REQUEST);` in the top of my includes file but i bet they can find it and disable, i need to be able to do it on server side.

Comment: Fire them if they can't understand the difference between these, or give them some training. You can't block _REQUEST. It has legitimate uses (When  a var can be in _GET and/or in _POST).

Comment: Look into request_order http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order in php.ini but it's an order variable, not sure it can toggle it off.

Comment: Dear John - what you need to fix is the team. $_REQUEST is not the only thing you are going to have a problem with if they cannot cooperate. I think that instead of making stuff in the code, you need to call a meeting and have a serious talk. Just my opinion.

Comment: Grzegorz this been done already and still same problems. I told my boss to stop working with them but he seems to be attached to their prices or something.

Comment: Old  habits die hard .. it would take some time for him to fix the team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure of any official way even `request_order`  does not mean it will leave the super globals array REQUEST empty.

What you can do is have your own little scanner .. looking of REQUEST in there code .. (Please Note this is just an experiment)

```
ini_set("display_erros", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

findUsage(__DIR__,'$_REQUEST');
```

Output Example

```
$_REQUEST Found in /public_html/www/stockoverflow/a.php Line 7 
$_REQUEST Found in /public_html/www/stockoverflow/c.php Line 3 
$_REQUEST Found in /public_html/www/stockoverflow/lib/phpThumb/demo/index.php Line 2 
$_REQUEST Found in /public_html/www/stockoverflow/lib/phpThumb/demo/phpThumb.demo.gallery.php Line 36 
$_REQUEST Found in /public_html/www/stockoverflow/lib/phpThumb/demo/phpThumb.demo.gallery.php Line 45 
$_REQUEST Found in /public_html/www/stockoverflow/lib/phpThumb/demo/phpThumb.demo.gallery.php Line 47 
$_REQUEST Found in /public_html/www/stockoverflow/lib/phpThumb/demo/phpThumb.demo.gallery.php Line 4
```

Function Used

```
function findUsage($projectDir,$find) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $di = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
    foreach ( $di as $file ) {
        if (! $file->isFile() || $file->getExtension() != "php")
            continue;
        $n = 0;
        foreach ( file($file) as $line ) {
            $n ++;
            if (strpos($line, $find) !== false) {
                echo $find, " Found in $file Line $n \n";
                flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you wanna do this to make your code safe, you can make your own `$_Request` and it's safe (put it in bootstrap)

```
$_REQUEST = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
```

Comment: This will not disable the $_REQUEST variable at all.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question.